# problems running image_publisher node

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! It's my first time I have to deal with images in ROS. As I am a beginner, I tried to run this node

```
rosrun image_publisher image_publisher /opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/images/splash.png
```

but I get

```
[ERROR] [1638817012.952972146]: Failed to load image (/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz/images/splash.png): cap_.isOpened() onInit /tmp/binarydeb/ros-melodic-image-publisher-1.14.0/src/nodelet/image_publisher_nodelet.cpp 147
```

I don' have a splash.png as far as I know.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392327/problems-running-image_publisher-node/) by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 44 on 2021-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @v.leto

The issue is the image path is incorrect,

If you are running Melodic then file path would be:

`/opt/ros/melodic/share/rviz/images/splash.png`

After running `rosrun image_publisher image_publisher /opt/ros/melodic/share/rviz/images/splash.png` then `image_publisher` will print a message such as:

```
[ INFO] [1638830830.340437700]: File name for publishing image is : /opt/ros/melodic/share/rviz/images/splash.png
[ INFO] [1638830830.348288400]: Flip horizontal image is : false
[ INFO] [1638830830.349854100]: Flip flip_vertical image is : false
```

To visualize, run another terminal `rqt`, under Plugins->ImageView, select from the drop down menu and you will be able to visualize image as shown below:

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2021-12-07**:
thank you very much @osilva. Is this the way to see images with open cv? I mean, I have to run rqt and then Plugins->ImageView? And if would like to see another .png image, where should I put it,

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-07**:
Yes you can see published images in OpenCV, you will need something called `cvbridge`. Here a link to get you started: http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-07**:
You can place your .png file in any file path, just change it:

`rosrun image_publisher image_publisher <file path>`

**Comment by [v.leto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37009/v.leto/) on 2021-12-07**:
thanks again!